# How to assess whether IQ predicts emotional experiment more at time 1 or time 2 controlling for covariates?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, panel-data, dataset, glmm

I have the following data set of a two-wave longitudinal study in educational psychology. A group of 400 people did some questionnaire on IQ, personality and two different emotional states (sadness and melancholy) at time 1 and one year later at time 2.

My  hypotheses are:

- IQ is a significant predictor emotionalstate1 and emotionalstate2 over and above the personality factors.
- IQ is a stronger predictor for emotionalstate2 than for emotionalstate1.

My variables are:

- time 1: IQ, five personality factors, emotionalstate1,
  emotionalstate2
- time 2: emotionalstate1 emotionalstate2

I did multiple regression for each emotional state and each time point separately. But how could I account for the repeated measurements in my analysis? Keep in mind that the assumption of independence in GLM will not be met then.